# Having Trouble Starting a New Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to install Laravel on my Mac and begin a new project. For some reason, I am unable to do that. I have googled for days. This is what I get when I try to make a new Laravel project:
[image]

Comment: How do you install it ? Is this guide (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation) do you follow ?

Comment: Also try running a [`composer clearcache`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#clear-cache-clearcache-) to purge Composer's internal package cache, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

try with composer like this: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel sopport-ticket-new 
And check the official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall laravel global from this method `composer global require "laravel/installer"` or update